# Citep or citet does not display references list?

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I am having an issue that randomly occurs while citing references.

When I type " \cite{ " in my file a list of references usually pops up and I can select any reference by selecting them, as such: 
[image: \cite]

However when I type " \citet " or " \citep ", this list does not appear most of the time. But the references appear on my PDF file as intended.

[image: \citep]

Moreover, after I manually type in the cite key and change `\cite` to `\citep` or `\citet` as required they become black and look like this:

Several times I have noticed that `\citet` and `\citep` both behave like `\cite`, however these occurences are random and I can not reproduce them. I am using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

The editor I use is TeXstudio 2.12.10.

I am wondering if anyone can help me solve this. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome. This lookup is a feature of whatever editor you're using, so you need to tell us which editor that is.

Comment: The red highligting of `\citet` could also suggest that your editor does not recognise the command. If a command is not recognised by your editor it is natural to assume that the editor will not recognise that command as a citation command and will not display the cite-autcomplete list. Note that your editors failure to recognise the command has no bearing on LaTeX's recognising the command (or not recognising the command): Only the error messages in the `.log` file after running LaTeX are relevant for that. The behaviour is editor-dependent, so we need to know what editor you use.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Many thanks for your reply. I am using TeXstudio 2.12.10. Hope this helps.

Comment: There is a deleted answer to another question which might be helpful for your problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgwjm.png (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116171/36296) Short summary: make sure command completion for natbib is activated, if this does not help you can create your own .cwl file.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks so much! That helped. I activated natbib.cwl and everything is working fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is perfectly answered by an (unfortunately) [deleted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116171/36296) by @Chris. As you cannot yet see deleted answers, I'll quote it here in a community wiki post:

> I think that your problem is that texstudio will not autocomplete
>   citekeys when you use commands other than `\cite`? If you want to add
>   `\citep` to the commands that are linked to your bibliography then you
>   need to provide some extra information to texstudio.
>
> From [the manual](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040), you need to create a `.cwl` file that lists the
>   autocomplete macros. Create a file in `~/.config/texstudio` called
>   `MacroList.cwl` for example. Add `\citep{keylist}` to that file. Then
>   in texstudio, select Options->Configure->Completion and select the
>   file you just created. When you use `\citep` it should now provide a
>   list of citekeys from your bibliography. It worked for me, anyway.
>
> EDIT
>
> I just realised that `citep` is part of `natbib`, which has a
>   predefined `cwl` file. In the list of `cwl` files (in the Completion
>   tab of the Configure window), select the `natbib.cwl` file. Then, all
>   of the macros defined by `natbib` should be set up correctly.